# Check certificate installed in system credential storage

Tags: android, ssl, keychain

My app is running on Android 4.0.1 and above. I use the following code to programmatically install a PKCS12 certificate in system-wide credential storage:

```
Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
byte[] p12 = readFile("myCa.p12");
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, p12);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code pops up system dialog to install the certificate, which means it needs user interaction, it is fine at this point.

Next, I would like to implement another function which can check **whether a specific certificate has already been installed or not in credential storage**(suppose I know certificate name & alias). I have no clue how to implement that? Could someone give me some suggestions please?

(It would be nice to have no user interaction from this function)

Answer (score 0):

When I played with droid's certificates I used this code to get certificates list (including installed by user):

```
public interface CertificateValidator {
    boolean valid(X509Certificate cert);
}

public boolean findInstalledCertificate(final CertificateValidator validator) {
    try {
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
        if (ks != null) {
            ks.load(null, null);
            final Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                final String alias = aliases.nextElement();
                final X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
                if (validator.valid(cert)) return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException
            | KeyStoreException
            | CertificateException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, you can check in `valid` method whether the next cert is yours or not.